# How does the get_matching_blocks() work?

Tags: python

Can please someone explain the behavior of the get_matching_blocks()? 
For the following example:

```
string2 = "1234 abc efg"
string1 = "efg abc 1234"
match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).get_matching_blocks()
print(match)
```

it returns the following result
    `[Match(a=3, b=4, size=5), Match(a=12, b=12, size=0)]`
meaning that it finds only the subsequence " abc "

Why doesn't it return also the subsequences "1234" and "efg"?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documenatation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks):

> Return list of triples describing matching subsequences. Each triple is of the form (i, j, n), and means that a[i:i+n] == b[j:j+n]. The triples are monotonically increasing in i and j.

The key words here are "monotonically increasing". This means that if the returned list contains triples `t = (i, j, n)` and `t' = (i', j', n')` where `t` appears before `t'`, we must have `i <= j <= i' <= j'`.

Comment: So why is ' abc ' the result? Shouldn't 'efg' be the first found sequence?

Comment: @Ame.Lia what happens if you reverse the arguments?

Comment: for match = SequenceMatcher(None, string2, string1).get_matching_blocks() I obtain again the same common string, " abc ". this is the output: [Match(a=4, b=3, size=5), Match(a=12, b=12, size=0)]

Comment: I modified the two strings by adding a space at the end of each string, and now the result is the string "1234 ". So it seems that besides the monotonically increasing index it might also return the longest string found. That is, if only one combination of monotonically increasing indexes is possible, then it will return the longest common string. Does is it seem plausible this explanation?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the last experiment was with the strings reversed (that is, first string 2 and then string 1)

Comment: @Ame.Lia It seems to me that the first match is for the substring which starts at the lowest index in the first parameter.

Comment: @Ame.Lia When you are experimenting, you should make only a single change at a time, rather than several changes all at once.

Comment: thank you for the advice, this is exactly what I did. In my first comment I made the modification you suggested (1st experiment) and got the same output as my initial try. This is why I don't think that in general the match is for the substring with the lowest index in the first parameter. In the second comment (2nd experiment) I kept the modification you suggested, and added an extra space at the end of the strings. It is only for this second experiment that the output is the 1st substring with the lowest index, but it is also a substring with a length equal with the one of the first result.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say "The triplets are monotonically increasing in i and j."  So the implementation will never look backwards after it has found a match.  It finds "abc" and only looks forward in each string from there.

Comment: And in this case how come it didn't find first "efg" and then stopped?